# Item not showing up in Search Results

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, search

We have an InfoPath form library that has about 6000 items in it.  We are using indexed columns and filters to view the items we need without having to worry about the list view threshold.

The issue is not ALL items in this list are showing up in Search.

I can setup a filter like thie

```
Employee Name  Begins with Gray
```

And it returns 3 documents for that name.  All three documents can be opened viewed edited.  We don't have versioning turned on so I don't think its an "Item hasn't been published so doesn't display in search results" kind of thing

When I search for that name it only shows 2 of those 3 documents.

I tried differing the search by other items in that form and searching for the file name itself and no good.

I have tried an Index Reset and full crawl.

I have exported out the site collection and imported it into another farm, ran the crawl and I get the same results.

These documents (it's been confirmed an issue on three separate documents so far) won't show up in search results on either farm.

Again these documents are all in the same form library so I don't think it can be a security thing with content access account.

I have searched the crawler errors to see if these documents were listed in there and they are not there either.

Do you guys have any clues as to where I can look to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

**From Central Admin:**

Have you checked the Crawl Log using the URL of the item? 
Crawl Log --> URL "tab" --> select URL or Host name and enter the item URL. Anything returned?

**Scopes**

Do you have any custom scopes setup that might exclude the items?

**Other items to check:**

Are you searching for items using an account that is a Site Collection Admin or Farm Admin? 
Are there any workflows running on the items? 
For testing, change the name of the missing documents to something simple like blue, green, or red (set the Name and Title fields).  Run a crawl. Anything?

If items are returned from the Crawl Log URL search, I'd suggest downloading a copy of Mossman's Fast for SharePoint tool from codeplex.  The tool will give you a lot of insight into the metadata and what is being crawled.

(i would have posted this as a comment, but i don't have enough points)

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: Query - settings - "remove duplicates"
[image]